# Find inverse of matrix using b^nth power

Tags: c, matrix

I've searched for hours and spent many more trying to figure how to fix this problem. I need to find the inverse of a predefined matrix using 
`A^-1 = I + (B + B^2 + ... + B^20)` where `B = I-A`.

```
void invA(double a[][3], double id[][3], double z[][3])
{
    int i, j, n, k;
    double pb[3][3]   = {1.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,1.};
    double temp[3][3] = {1.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,1.};
    double b[3][3];

    temp[i][j] = 0;
    b[i][j]    = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            b[i][j] = id[i][j] - a[i][j];

    for (n = 0; n < 20; n++)                        //run loop n times
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)                     //find b to the power 20
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    temp[i][j] += pb[i][k] * b[k][j];

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)                      //allocate pb from temp
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
                pb[i][j] = temp[i][j];

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)                       //summing b n time
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)                   //to find inverse
                z[i][j] = z[i][j] + pb[i][j];
    }
}
```

Matrix `a` is the defined matrix, `id` is the identity and `z` is the inverse (result). I can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong.

Comment: To clarify, I need `for (n = 0; n < 20; n++)` to calculate the B matrix to the power of 1 to 20. Then I need sum all the values of B through B^20. Finally add that sum to the identity matrix to get the inverse. I think I have an idea after this post.

Answer (score 2):

You have few problems.

First, `temp[i][j] = 0;` and `b[i][j] = 0;` at the beginning of the function use uninitialized variables `i` and `j`. The behaviour is undefined, and who knows how `temp` is actually initialized.

Then, `temp` must be reinitialized to a zero matrix *at each iteration*. I don't know what exactly does your code compute, but it is not a power for sure.

Finally, (unless `z` is initialized to `I`), you are missing the initial term.

All that said, I highly recommend to factor out most of the loops into functions: `matAdd()` and `matMult()`. Once they are unit tested, the rest is much simpler.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that first one. I understand the second one. But the third item? In the `invA()`  my `z[][3]` is initialized in my `int main()`.

Comment: @Chris Re third item, that's exactly what I meant. Without seeing `main` it is hard to tell that `z`is indeed initialized to an identity. I highly recommend to do it in `invA`.